# For-loop pattern that increments the last column by 1

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to make a for-loop program that prints the same digits or integers every row except the last column which is being incremented by 1.

Example:

```
     1 1 1 1 1 2

     2 2 2 2 2 3

     3 3 3 3 3 4

     4 4 4 4 4 5

     5 5 5 5 5 6

     6 6 6 6 6 7
```

Here is my code

```
int main(){
int num,value;
scanf("%d", &num);

for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    for(int j=i; j < i+num; j++){
        value = i;
        printf("%d ", value);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

I have also tried doing this

```
int num,value;
scanf("%d", &num);

for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < i+num; j++){
        value = i;
        if(value < j){
            value+=1;
        }
        printf("%d ", value);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

However, I got this as a result

```
   1 2 2 2 2 2

   2 3 3 3 3 3

   3 4 4 4 4 4

   4 5 5 5 5 5

   5 5 5 5 5 6

   6 6 6 6 6 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand how you are getting those two extra columns, but to get the last column as 1 incremented you can simply use this.

```
for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < i+num; j++){
        if(j==(i+num)-1)
            printf("%d ",i+1);
        else
            printf("%d ", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did. I am not doing the updation of i in the first for loop. Rather I am checking if I have reached the last column in the second for loop then update i to i++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num, value;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (int i=1; i<num; ) {
    
        for (int j=i; j<(num+i); j++) {
            if (j == (num+i-1)) {
                i++;
                printf("%d", i);
                break;
            }
        
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```